# Caesar Cipher, stuck on "validating the key"

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am working on Caesar problem set in CS50 Harvard course and I am going step by step through the problem and am stuck on "validating the key".

> Now that you know how to read the key, let’s analyze it. Modify `caesar.c` such that instead of printing out the command-line argument provided, your program instead checks to make sure that each character of that command line argument is a decimal digit (i.e., 0, 1, 2, etc.) and, if any of them are not, terminates after printing the message `Usage: ./caesar key`. But if the argument consists solely of digit characters, you should convert that string (recall that `argv` is an array of strings, even if those strings happen to look like numbers) to an actual integer, and print out the integer, as via `%i` with `printf`. So, for example, the behavior might look like this:
>
> ```
> $ ./caesar 20
> Success
> 20
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> $ ./caesar 20x
> Usage: ./caesar key
> ```

Every time I try mine it prints out everything twice and I cannot figure out why.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])

    {
//If command is not 2
//Use atoi to convert a string into that number
if (argc !=2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./ctest key\n");
    return 1;
}

//Find length of second string

else if (argc == 2)
{
    //Check if the key is a number
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
    //Check if it is not a digit
        if(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Needs to be a digit\n");
            return 1;
        }
    
        else
        
        {
            printf("Success\n %i \n", k);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using the new spin-off https://cs50.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @JohnKugelman is it that new at all? I just checked and it seems it exists for at least 3 years now.

Answer (score 3):

In order to meet the requirements for the program's output, you have to move not only *the success printout outside of the `for` loop*, but also remove the `Needs to be a digit` printout. You don't even need a loop, e. g.:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || argv[1][strspn(argv[1], "1234567890")])
    {
        puts("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;
    }

    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Success\n%i\n", k);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is helpful!  What is char *argv[]?  I was using string argv[]

Comment: `char *` is the same as `string`, just without the need to `#include "cs50.h"` which defines `string`.